# Libcurl - checking the server shutdown connection?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm still trying to figure out how to use Libcurl to determine IMMEDIATELY that the server has terminated the connection.

I'm giving a simple minimum working example - what I want to do:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include <curl.h>

std::deque<CURL *> my_global_deq_curl_easy;
CURL *CURL_;
CURLM *CURLM_;

static size_t my_write_data_BODY_func(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
                                      void *my_void_p) {
    if (size == 0) {
        std::cout << "size == 0" << std::endl;
    }
    return size * nmemb;
}

int closesocket_callback(void *clientp, curl_socket_t item) {
    std::cout << "LIBCURL_WANT_CLOSE_SOCKET" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void my_Infinity_loop() {
    int num_desc_events;
    int running_now;

    while (1) {
        curl_multi_poll(CURLM_, NULL, 0, 1000000,
                        &num_desc_events); // Waiting for the event

        if (my_global_deq_curl_easy.size() > 0) {
            // If a task is added to our queue, then add curl_easy to
            // multi_handle:
            curl_multi_add_handle(CURLM_, my_global_deq_curl_easy.front());

            my_global_deq_curl_easy.pop_back();
        }

        curl_multi_perform(CURLM_, &running_now);

        if (running_now == 0) {
            std::cout << "REQUEST "
                         "DONE:------------------------------------------------"
                         "-----------------------------------------------------"
                         "-----------------------------------------------"
                      << std::endl;

            curl_multi_remove_handle(CURLM_, CURL_);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    int status;
    std::thread my_thread(my_Infinity_loop);

    //---------------------------------------------------
    CURLM_ = curl_multi_init();
    //---------------------------------------------------
    CURL_ = curl_easy_init();
    //---------------------------------------------------

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    curl_easy_setopt(CURL_, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.state.gov/");

    curl_easy_setopt(CURL_, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,
                     1); // debug information output to the console

    curl_easy_setopt(
        CURL_, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,
        my_write_data_BODY_func); // So that the resulting html is not output to
                                  // the console - so that it does not interfere

    curl_easy_setopt(
        CURL_, CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION,
        closesocket_callback); // set callback function - when Libcurl is ready
                               // to close the socket

    //---------------------------------------------------
    my_global_deq_curl_easy.push_back(
        CURL_); // adding a conditional task to the queue

    curl_multi_wakeup(CURLM_); // Wake up curl_multi_poll in other thread
    //---------------------------------------------------

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(
        std::chrono::seconds(55)); // We are waiting 55 seconds for the Server
                                   // to close the connection!

    //---------------------------------------------------
    // And we re-make a request on the same Curl_easy descriptor to the same
    // site:

    my_global_deq_curl_easy.push_back(CURL_);
    std::cout << "start:" << std::endl; //
    curl_multi_wakeup(CURLM_);
    //---------------------------------------------------

    my_thread.join();
}
```

If you run this code, you will see the following:

**1**-First Libcurl Executes the first request to the specified site - [www.state.gov](http://www.state.gov).

**2**-According to the debug information that is displayed on the console, you can see the progress of the connection.

**3**-When running_now == 0, it means LIbcurl has executed the request.

**4**-The server leaves the connection open with some timeout.

**5**-Therefore, we will pause for 55 seconds to wait until the server closes the connection.

**6**-Now we make a repeat request to the same server via the same curl_easy handle.

And thanks to the debug information, we can see the following on the console:

> start:
>
> Connection 0 seems to be dead!
>
> - Closing connection 0
> - schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with [www.state.gov](http://www.state.gov) port 443
>
> LIBCURL_WANT_CLOSE_SOCKET   //call_back triggered (CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION)

That is! While waiting for 55 seconds - the remote server closed the connection! But Libcurl ONLY found out about this when it started making a new request.

My question is: can Libcur Libcurl let you know about the connection being closed by the remote server - IMMEDIATELY after the connection is closed by the server - and not after some time only during the repeated request ??

Comment: Have you inspected your curl headers in-flight?   I get the impression you want the closing to happen immediately after the first completed transfer.  The `'keep-alive' ` header might work for you.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe, I didn't understand anything from what you wrote. I want ONLY ONE THING, to determine that the server has closed the connection - to determine it IMMEDIATELY.

Comment: My apologies. If you send a header `keep-alive` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive the server will wait for, and expect,  more requests. This is probably(my guess) why you're not getting the close callback when you want/expect  it.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe, I can't understand why you decided that I need a keep-alive header? On the basis of what did you decide that ?

Comment: I'm saying `keep-alive` is the opposite of what you need. curl might send a keep-alive or it might be a default. Try to set the opposite. Check if `Connection: close` works for you.

Comment: @273K, Unfortunately this is not true again :( Recv returns zero IMMEDIATELY when the remote server has performed a shutdown. This is stated in the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv , it is also said in the POSIX documentation: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html

Answer (score 1):

> When running_now == 0, it means LIbcurl has executed the request

Yes, and it has *completed* the request. If the connection was closed, that happened already and then libcurl has an error code for that transfer.

Your code doesn't seem to check the return code so you won't know if it succeeded or failed (which it would if the connection was closed mid-transfer).

Typically libcurl doesn't care about if the connection is closed or not at the end of a successful transfer.

**libcurl does nothing with the connection *between* transfers, so therefore it doesn't know if the connection is closed at some point after libcurl's last use of it. That's why it might notice the dead connection again first when you make a subsequent request to the host.**

You can use [CURLOPT_MAXAGE_CONN](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MAXAGE_CONN.html) to prevent libcurl from trying to reuse connections that are older than a certain number of seconds. In your case for example, you could set that to 50 and then libcurl will never reuse a connection that it has left idle that long (and instead close that and create a new one).

But to go back the final question:

> can libcurl let you know about the connection being closed by the remote server - IMMEDIATELY after the connection is closed by the server?

If that connection close happens *after* the transfer was completed, the simple answer is **no**.

(I'm the lead author of libcurl)

Answer (score -1):

You seem to expect this series of events to happen:

1. Client sends request
2. Server reads request
3. Server writes response
4. Client reads response
5. Server closes connection
6. Client sees that the connection is closed

This doesn't work, because the client determines the length of the response from the headers, and as soon as it reads this number of bytes, *it stops looking at the connection*, and the shutdown happens *after* that. It will start using a connection again when you ask it to do another transfer.

Let's examine the sequence in more details:

3a: Server writes headers that indicate length of response, say 1000 bytes.
3b: Server writes 1000 bytes of response by calling `send(socket, buffer, 1000, ...)`
4a: Client reads headers.
4b: Client reads 1000 bytes of response by calling `recv(socket, buffer, 1000, ...)`
4c: Client finishes with request and returns to caller.
5: Server closes connection by calling `shutdown`

You seem to assume that 5 happens before 4b is completed, and the knowledge about it will be used by ongoing `recv` at the client side. This is not the case. When the server closes the connection, and the information about it is ready to be consumed, the client is already done with this particular request. Its `recv` has already returned. Too late. There is no "4b1: try to read another couple of bytes to see that maybe the connection was closed". You need to initiate another request to see the shutdown.